# C# WPF SQLite index out of range exception

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

Below is my C# code

```
query = "Select german from words where polish='"+enteredword+"';";
command.CommandText = query;
datareader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (datareader.Read())
     {
        outword = datareader.GetString(1);
        MessageBox.Show(outword);
      }
```

I have a problem with this part of code. Im getting error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" in this line

```
outword = datareader.GetString(1);
```

Where is the problem? I cant solve it

Comment: what are your results in datareader?  I think you may need to put 0 not 1

Comment: Arrays start at index 0. Everywhere. You retrieve just one field so there is only one index available in the reader buffer. The field is at index 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 2):

You only select *one* field. As indexes are zero-based, this

```
outword = datareader.GetString(1);
```

needs to be:

```
outword = datareader.GetString(0);
```

This is probably test code, in your real code, please use `using` blocks and parameters in your queries instead of injection prone string formatting.